# Android studio-failing to download the content

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a simple app with 1 button & 1 image in which when the button is pressed the image is downloaded from the URL and displayed. But as I click the button my App crashes. How can I fix this?

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView downloadedImg;

    public void downloadImage(View view) {

        // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png

        ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap myImage;

        try {
            myImage = task.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();

            downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Interaction", "Button Tapped");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadedImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return myBitmap;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what is the error?

Comment: Kindly add the error message from IDE

Comment: Please post the LogCat output to help us understand your error.

Comment: Is this your complete code, can you please paste complete code as well as logs?
Can you check if "myImage" not null.

Comment: If there is an error, please try providing the error message or the stack trace as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this

```
ImageView downloadedImg;

public void downloadImage(View view) {

    // https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png

    ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
    Bitmap myImage;

    try {
      task.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png");



    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Log.i("Interaction", "Button Tapped");

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    downloadedImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

}

public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      Bitmap myBitmap; 
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return myBitmap;

    }

@Override
protected void onPostExcecute(Bitmap bitmap){
   downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

}
```